# What standard errors are returned with predict.glm(..., type = "response", se.fit = TRUE)?

Tags: r, statistics, regression, glm, confidence-interval

I am going to fit the model on the data provided in this [excellent example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14424417) on how to compute the 95% confidence interval for the response, after performing a logistic regression:

```
foo <- mtcars[,c("mpg","vs")]; names(foo) <- c("x","y")
mod <- glm(y ~ x, data = foo, family = binomial)
preddata <- with(foo, data.frame(x = seq(min(x), max(x), length = 100)))
preds <- predict(mod, newdata = preddata, type = "link", se.fit = TRUE)

critval <- 1.96 ## approx 95% CI
upr <- preds$fit + (critval * preds$se.fit)
lwr <- preds$fit - (critval * preds$se.fit)
fit <- preds$fit

fit2 <- mod$family$linkinv(fit)
upr2 <- mod$family$linkinv(upr)
lwr2 <- mod$family$linkinv(lwr)
```

Now, my question comes from the fact that you can get the response directly, simply by asking for

```
predict(..., type = 'response', se.fit = TRUE)
```

without transforming

```
predict(..., type = 'link', se.fit = TRUE)
```

However, this produces different standard errors. ***What are these errors and can they be directly used to calculate the confidence interval on the fitted response values?***

The code in `predict.glm` that is relevant is this:

```
switch(type, response = {
    se.fit <- se.fit * abs(family(object)$mu.eta(fit))
    fit <- family(object)$linkinv(fit)
}, link = , terms = )
```

and comparing outputs:

```
preds_2 <- predict(mod, newdata = preddata, type = "response", se.fit = TRUE)


> head(preds_2$fit)
         1          2          3          4          5          6 
0.01265744 0.01399994 0.01548261 0.01711957 0.01892627 0.02091959 

> head(preds_2$se.fit)
         1          2          3          4          5          6 
0.01944681 0.02098841 0.02263473 0.02439022 0.02625902 0.02824491
```

It doesn't seem very obvious how to go from the above to:

```
> head(fit2)
         1          2          3          4          5          6 
0.01265744 0.01399994 0.01548261 0.01711957 0.01892627 0.02091959 
> head(upr2)
        1         2         3         4         5         6 
0.2130169 0.2184891 0.2240952 0.2298393 0.2357256 0.2417589 
> head(lwr2)
           1            2            3            4            5            6 
0.0006067975 0.0007205942 0.0008555502 0.0010155472 0.0012051633 0.0014297930
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you look at `?family`, you will see that `$mu.eta` is the derivative of `mu` over `eta` (i.e., the derivative of inverse link function). Therefore, `se.fit = TRUE` for `type = "response"` gives a first order approximation for the true standard error. This is known as "delta method".

Of course, since inverse link function is generally non-linear, the confidence interval is not symmetric around fitted values. So getting the confidence interval on the link scale, then mapping it back to response scale is the way to go.

Comment: thanks, I wish they will take a line from your first paragraph and put in the documentation in `?predict.glm`.

Comment: link scale is usually more accurate than response scale because of the way it accounts for the non-linearity of the link function.  But both are asymptotically valid.